# Empty body in supertest request with application/vnd

Tags: json, node.js, express, supertest

I'm having a lot of trouble sending a request body in a supertest post. I've read the solutions to other questions, which blame improper configuration of body-parser, but those answers are referring to a custom datatype. ([res.body is empty in this test that uses supertest and Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26429997/res-body-is-empty-in-this-test-that-uses-supertest-and-node-js)). I configure body-parser like this:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb', type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

This solution to the post I've provided says "supertest uses [this](https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db/blob/master/db.json) file to determine if you are sending json or not." My content type is actually listed there, so I don't see why this should be a problem.

I am attempting to post a request like so:

```
it ('creates user', function (done) {
    var user = {
      firstname: 'Joe',
      lastname: 'JoeJoe',
      email: 'joe@joe.com',
      password: 'spartacus',
    };

    request(app)
      .post('/api/users')
      .send(user)
      .expect(200)
      .expect('Sent email to joe@joe.com', done)
  });
});
```

And I import my app with this line:

```
var app = require('../server.js');
```

Where server.js configures my application entirely. Is this application type supported by supertest? Is there a way to force the user data to be noticed as part of req.body?

Comment: Don't forget to send the content-type header of 'application/vnd.api+json'

Comment: Could you explain where to set that?

Comment: `request(app)
      .post('/api/users', { headers: {  'content-type': 'application/vnd.api+json' } })`

Comment: Hm I tried that but the body is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue can be solved by setting the `content-type` header on your `post` request to `application/vnd.api+json`. You can do so in supertest/superagent as follows:

```
it ('creates user', function (done) {
    var user = {
      firstname: 'Joe',
      lastname: 'JoeJoe',
      email: 'joe@joe.com',
      password: 'spartacus',
    };

    request(app)
      .post('/api/users')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.api+json')
      .send(user)
      .expect(200)
      .expect('Sent email to joe@joe.com', done)
  });
});
```